# android DRM problem

Tags: android, drm

I am an android developer and I am developing now an android application that can download and read epub files with drm.

I am now struggling to understand how this drm works and I got messages from the RMSDK such as "No device provider implementation" ...

Has anybody came through this? Can anybody explain to me how to work with the DRM on an android system?

Thank in advance

Comment: Presumably you need to work with the DRM provider to figure out the correct way to read the file.

Comment: check this article which i wrote recently : http://aameer.github.io/articles/digital-rights-management-multi-drm/  it explains in details about how to achieve multi-drm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting looking around for a good and reliable DRM client for Android:

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=+DRM+Client+for+Android&c=apps

and after that, download the documentation the DRM on how to encode/encrypt your content with the DRM software.

For a good explanation of the principles behind DRM:

http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/DRM

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management

For a specific DRM implementation I like this diagram (non-Android related):

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC498598.png

and its writeup here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189079(v=vs.95).aspx

The details may differ among the different DRM software though.